# Symfony: How to use the createTable () method of PdoSessionHandler?

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to persist the sessions of my application (Symfony 4) in the database. The drawback is that I cannot understand how to use the following code and that it indicates the Symfony documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/pdo_session_storage.html.

```
try {
    $sessionHandlerService->createTable();
} catch (\PDOException $exception) {
    // the table could not be created for some reason
}
```

Comment: The image contains the same code as you have included here. Why did you post the image additionally? Did you want to show us something else?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question. Thanks. The image contains the same code.

Answer (score -1):

After you have set the dsn for the pdo session handler, as described [on the page you linked already](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/pdo_session_storage.html), you can use the [dependency injection](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html#container-aware-migrations) for symfony to first get a `PdoSessionHandler` and then just call the function. For example, *if* you're using doctrine migrations, in a migration do:

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareTrait;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\PdoSessionHandler;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Schema;
use Doctrine\Migrations\AbstractMigration;

class Version20191028200000 extends AbstractMigration implements ContainerAwareInterface {
    use ContainerAwareTrait;

    public function up(Schema $schema) {
        $pdoSessionHandler = $this->container->get(PdoSessionHandler::class); // or alias!
        $pdoSessionHandler->createTable();
    }

    public function down(Schema $schema) {
        // empty, or $this->addSql('DROP TABLE sessions'); <-- use correct table name!
    }
}
```

Please note, that this is only marginally different from just copying the appropriate create statement from [`PdoSessionHandler::createTable`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/591ad2203c90150fa4fdad82989d7a8a5060f3bb/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/Handler/PdoSessionHandler.php#L215) and putting it into `$this->addSql(...)`, which would actually output the query when executing the migration.

Also note, that you might have to make the `PdoSessionHandler` service public (it's possibly not by default) or use an alias instead.

Comment: Hi, i use doctrine migrations, but I get errors:

  Argument 1 passed to DoctrineMigrations\Version20191027161025::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\H  
  andler\PdoSessionHandler, instance of Doctrine\Migrations\Version\Version given, called in *********/vend  
  or/doctrine/migrations/lib/Doctrine/Migrations/Version/Version.php on line 65

Comment: and if add code:


        $pdoSessionHandler = new PdoSessionHandler();
        $pdoSessionHandler->createTable();

in method up up(Schema $schema), i get error :

In PdoSessionHandler.php line 431:
                            
  invalid data source name  
                            
thanks

Comment: @IDEASANDCODES oh, which symfony version are you using? And why don't you just create the table by hand, ffs?

Comment: I use symfony 4.3. I wanted to know how to use this method, without using entity or generating the table manually. thanks

Comment: @IDEASANDCODES updated my answer. https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html#container-aware-migrations okay, you would have to make your session handler public (or give it an alias) to fetch it from the container.

Comment: Thanks Jakumi, but it didn't work for me. For now, I will continue to use entities to work the sessions in the database.

Thanks again.